# React Native: Upload Picture from local path to Firebase storage

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'd simply like to upload an image from a local path on my mobile device to Firebase Storage. I get this image using a module called ImagePicker and it provides me with a path that is formatted like this:

```
"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.explr/files/Pictures/image-468dccf5-35a0-42cc-9910-1f8ba83c9bf8.jpg"
```

I've read on a post that this wasn't possible due to differences between react for the web and react for mobile, but that post was from 2016.
So did anything change? Is it possible now?

Thanks for helping!